# Difference between Web Streams and Node.js Stream APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser, stream

I'm building a file upload application to familiarize myself with the concept of streams. I'm trying to turn a file list or blobs into a stream then upload it to the backend and store it on the file system.

I had no issue with frontend and backend implementations respectively but I'm having a hard time connecting the two. My main problem is that I don't understand the difference between the [Web Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API#Concepts_and_usage) and the [Node.js Streams API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream). I managed to turn the blobs of selected input files in the browser into a Web `ReadableStream` but the packages I tried (`axios` for requests, `socket.io` and `socket.io-stream` for WebSocket) only accept the Node.js version Stream as arguments. I also could not pipe a Web ReadableStream into a Node.js Writeable or Duplex Stream. The method names are also different (e.g.: `pipeTo` or `pipeThrough` in Web API and `pipe` in Node.js API).

I know there are implementation differences between Node.js and browsers but naively, I thought the APIs would be similar. Can I somehow trivially convert between Web streams and browserified Node.js streams and I'm missing something? Does it worth using the Web Stream API over [`stream-browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-browserify)?

Comment: This needs some sample code. I can't tell whether OP's confusion lies on the front-end or the back-end. You can't use Node streams in browserland, and for that reason I assume there is no browserland library that expects a Node stream. On the back-end, you're only dealing with Node streams: even data streamed to the server using a browserland stream would present as a Node stream on the server side. Without some code, it's hard to imagine where in all creation OP's problem could even exist.

Comment: `axios` probably has just confusing types, their browser API allows only `FormData`, `File`, and `Blob`, in addition to the common ones like `string`, `ArrayBuffer`, etc. Their server API has `Stream` and `Buffer` though, so I thought I can use this on the frontend too.

I can't remember why I couldn't make `socket.io` work, you're right that I should have added sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not too difficult to convert a web stream to a Node.js stream manually, but you should really try to find a library that accepts native web streams instead of shoehorning a Node.js shim for the `stream` built-in into the browser with Browserify.

However, if it proves necessary to use a Node.js stream shim in the browser, you need to install `stream-browserify` and use like this:

```js
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream-browserify;'

// window.ReadableStream to Node.js Readable
const webRSToNodeRS = rs => {
  const reader = rs.getReader();
  const out = new Readable();
  reader.read().then(async ({ value, done }) => {
    while (!done) {
      out.push(value);
      ({ done, value } = await reader.read());
    }
    out.push(null);
  });
  return out;
}

// window.WritableStream to Node.js Writable
const webWSToNodeWS = ws => {
  const writer = ws.getWriter();
  const out = new Writable();
  out._write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    writer.write(chunk);
    callback();
  };
  out._final = callback => {
    writer.close();
    callback();
  };
  return out;
}
```

These methods should be enough to have full interop between web and Node streams. For example, if you want to pipe a web ReadableStream to a Node.js Writable/Duplex:

```js
const pipeWebRSToWritable = (rs, writable) => {
  // After converting you can use the normal pipe methods
  webRSToNodeRS(rs).pipe(writable);
}
```

However I'd like to mention that you don't need a library to stream data from the client to the server. The `fetch` API natively supports web streams and is probably the way you should go.

```js
// POST a ReadableStream (perhaps of a file) to the server
// Way easier and more performant than using a 3rd party library...
const postRSToServer = rs => fetch('/your/server/endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: rs
});
```

Last note: make sure you're directly using the [`Blob.prototype.stream` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream) (call this on a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, e.g. `file.stream()`, since `File` extends `Blob`). There are some ways to get a `ReadableStream` from a file in JS that actually end up loading all of the file into memory in the browser, which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! My use case is that I encrypt files in the browser then upload the encrypted chunks over WebSocket. Sending larger files (>5GB) in requests didn't work for me reliably, probably because of my server setup, so I switched to WebSocket but I'll definitely revisit using requests.

Comment: `({ done, value }) = await reader.read();` gives me `Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern` in babel and `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` in Node.js.  Is that valid syntax?

Comment: You're right, you need parentheses around the entire assignment. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

As per docs, since version 16, Node.js includes a  (still experimental) [implementation of the  WebStreams API](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html#web-streams-api).

And the old Stream API has now (since v. 17) gained some [toWeb/FromWeb](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadabletowebstreamreadable) methods to bridge both.

Some info [here](https://www.jasnell.me/posts/webstreams).

Answer (score 3):

For those (like myself) hitting this question in regard to the streams returned by `node-fetch`, note that [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) is a **web-compatible** implementation of `fetch` that [may eventually become the official node implementation](https://css-tricks.com/web-streams-everywhere-and-fetch-for-node-js/).

Also, see [leonbloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683586/11950764) RE the new toWeb/fromWeb methods, and WebStreams API.